# Total concentration conversion

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, concentration, mixtures, water-treatment

when dealing with waste water and the total values of P, N, C are given in ppm units, what molecular weight is used for converting from ppm to molar?

[image]

for Example- what will be 12 ppm of P(T) in Molar unit?

Comment: What  (T) in P(T) means ?

Comment: T stands for Total

Comment: Then it is easy - use the phosphorus molar mass, about 31 g/mol, i.e. about 31 ppm = 1 mol P/L. But consider some P is not in form.of simple phosphate. I remember mineralisation of waste water by peroxodisulphate for further analysis.